# How does google script lock works?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to understand how the google script lock works.

For better understanding let me create a scenario:

Lets suppose there are (script1,script2....script30) 30 simultaneous script running which is the limit from google.

Now comes another script "script31"

script31 goes like this:

```
function xyz()
{
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  
  try { lock.waitLock(10000); } //wait 10 sec

//  Do lots of stuff - read sheet and write in many rows and columns

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // applies all pending spreadsheet changes
lock.releaseLock();

}
```

Now my question is how will the script work.
If there are already 30 script running will it wait for one script to get finished?

Lets say out of 30 script now only 29 are running simultaneously. will my script31 get executed after waiting for 10 sec?

will this condition repeat with Script32, Script33 .. and so on who are waiting in line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of what the script does, any script that is executed in excess of 30 simultaneous running scripts will throw an exception:

**Exception messages**

If a script reaches a quota or limitation, it throws an exception with a message similar to the following:

> `There are too many scripts running simultaneously for this Google user account`

This indicates that you have too many scripts executing at once, although not necessarily the same script. Like the exception above, this most commonly occurs for custom functions that are called repeatedly in a single spreadsheet.

Script Locks, on the other hand, only work for simultaneous executions of a **defined section of code**, between the `waitLock` and `releaseLock` methods. If the other simultaneous executions do not execute code scoped within the lock, they will continue to execute.

**References:**

[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

[Class Lock](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock)

Comment: @Carlos_M Yes I am aware of that, will the script lock not be able to help at some extent? If not what is a way out?

Comment: Edited answer. Script lock will only work to prevent two instances of the same code running at the same time. If there are 30 different scripts running at the same time then you need to wait for one to be finished to execute the next script.